# Angular 4 Http Post put response in object

Tags: angular, angular-http

I'm using Angular 4 combined with an Asp.net web api. I don't know how I can read the properties of my respond.

My response looks likes this[image: Response]

My post request:

```
  postLogin(values: string): Observable<string> {
    let body = "username=test@test.test&password=Test1234!&grant_type=password";
    /*let body = values + "&grant_type=password";*/
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this._http.post(this._postLoginUrl, body, options)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

And my actually call to the post method:

```
this._loginService.postLogin(value)
        .subscribe(
          data => console.log(data),
          err => console.log(err));
```

And this does work, I do get the response in my Console[image: Response]

But how can I read my properties?

**UPDATE**

I've updated my code a bit but it still doesn't work like I want to, I did read the documentation but I still couldn't get further.

My new call to the post method:

```
console.log("username=" + this.username + "&password=" + this.password);
  this._loginService.postLogin("username=" + this.username + "&password=" + this.password)
    .subscribe(
      user => this.user = user),
      err => console.log(err);
```

And my new post request:

```
  postLogin(values: string): Observable<User> {
    let body = values + "&grant_type=password";
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this._http.post(this._postLoginUrl, body, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

With as extractData function

```
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.fields || {};
  }
```

If I do a console log of my user object now, I get undefined and if I try to access a property of user, my browser starts refreshing. What I am doing wrong, why can't I access my data?

Comment: Please read the documentation.

Comment: As said, read the docs... Here's your answer: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#extract-data :) But I *highly* recommend to read the whole thing ;)

Comment: Read the docs, as said! Regardless of post method, you'll need to parse the JSON response. Do it here on the return value in your service `return this._http.post(this._postLoginUrl, body, options).map(res => res.json())`

Comment: As @joh04667 said, you must deserialize using .json() method on response

Comment: Updated question, still having problems.

Comment: I don't think `body.fields` will be defined... based on your console log from before, your key options are `access_token` etc... try console.log(body) after the deserialize.

Comment: If you want the list of keys in the JSON, try `Object.keys(body)`. It's not at all clear what you expected `.fields` to be.

Comment: You could use a [typed response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49741323/2093371):

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
JSON.parse(data._body)
```

this will give you the response object.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from your response,

```ts
{"access_token":"blaablaa", .... }
```

there is not any `fields` in your data that you are receiving, but "just" an object with properties. Since there is no `fields`, therefore you should only return the actual response:

```ts
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body || {}; // remove 'fields'
}
```

And when you are receiving your data you can easily access the fields

```ts
this._loginService.postLogin(value)
    .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data.access_token) // your access_token
    })
```