# How do I get the post json when there is a 404 error?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a service call that when it returns a 404 error, I want to display the message that comes from the server when the status is 404. So, in event of an error or success, I get a post json that gives me a status code and message that indicates if it was successful or not.

Currrently, I have this service call:

```
 this._transactionService.findExistingTransaction(user, searchNumber)
       .subscribe(data => {

       this.transactionResponse = data;
       console.log(JSON.stringify(this.transactionResponse));

       this.router.navigate(['/edit-transaction-portal'], {queryParams: {bill: searchNumber}});

       this.onDismiss();
      }, (err) => { this.displayErrors = true;});
```

on error, it will set the bool displayErrors = true and then I can show the error message in my UI.

In html code:

```
 <input #inputtedNumber class="transactionInput" placeholder="{{numberPlaceholder | translate }}"/>
        <div class="error-msg1" *ngIf="displayErrors" style="margin-left:90px;" name="errorMsg">
           {{transactionResponse._errorDetails._message}} </div>
```

This is the json that gets posted back when I directly try to access api endpoint:

```
{  
   "_transactionNumber":null,
   "_order":null,
   "_errorDetails":{  
      "_status":"404",
      "_message":"Number is not available"
   }
}
```

I bind to the transactionResponse object that I get back from my service call. Unfortunately, although I believe this should work, I get the issue that _errorDetails is undefined and so nothing shows up.

I wonder if this is the right setup for something like this? If now, how can I fix it?

Thanks!

EDIT: Duplicate SO post with no answer: [How to read Custom error message from backend in Angular 4/2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324494/how-to-read-custom-error-message-from-backend-in-angular-4-2)

Comment: Create StackBlitz example of your problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The response body from the server should be in the `error` property of the error response that comes back in the `error` callback.

Regarding [HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse#description), the documentation states:

- A response that represents an error or failure, either from a non-successful HTTP status, an error while executing the request, or some other failure which occurred during the parsing of the response.
- Any error returned on the `Observable` response stream will be wrapped in an `HttpErrorResponse` to provide additional context about the state of the HTTP layer when the error occurred. The error property will contain either a wrapped `Error` object or the error response returned from the server.

If you want to use the same `transactionResponse` to display the errors, then assign the `error` property of the `err` that comes back to `this.transactionResponse`.

**Service Call**

```
this._transactionService.findExistingTransaction(user, searchNumber).subscribe(
   (data) => {

     this.transactionResponse = data;
     console.log(JSON.stringify(this.transactionResponse));

     this.router.navigate(['/edit-transaction-portal'], {queryParams: {bill: searchNumber}});

     this.onDismiss();
  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    this.displayErrors = true;

    // assign the error property of the err that comes back to the transactionResponse
    this.transactionResponse = err.error;
  });
```

**HTML**
Then this will work.

```
<input #inputtedNumber class="transactionInput" placeholder="{{ numberPlaceholder | translate }}"/>
<div class="error-msg1" *ngIf="displayErrors" style="margin-left:90px;" name="errorMsg">
    {{transactionResponse._errorDetails._message}}
</div>
```

There was some work done to this part of Angular in September 2017. [parse error response body for responseType "json"](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19477) So you may need to update Angular depending on your version.

This solution was tested on the following:

- Node v8.2.1
- NPM v5.3.0
- Angular CLI: 1.7.2
- Angular: 5.0.0

**Edit: StackBlitz example**

[HttpErrorResponse StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shybo7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

This example makes some assumptions about what the service looks like and what endpoint it is calling. The service makes a `POST` call to `www.google.com`. This fails and returns an `HttpErrorResponse`.

```
{
  "isTrusted": true
}
```

The `error` property of the `HttpErrorResponse` is assigned to `this._transactionResponse`. This can then be accessed in the template and displayed in the browser.

Comment: I have the latest angular version and it still doesn't work. I get the error, "Cannot read property '_errorDetails' of undefined for the binding set in my html. If I add the ? operator, I only get: "http://~/api/transactions/U004/search/bill/fgfgf 404 (Not Found)" message in the console window.

Comment: Can you make a StackBlitz to show your test example?

Comment: @Euridice01 The answer has been updated with a link to a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shybo7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @TarunLalwani unfortunately, not yet :( I'm trying to see why it doesn't work for me in my case I highlighted above.

Comment: @josavish, where are you setting isTrusted json?

Comment: The dev server that Stack Blitz uses is returning that response. If you try to hit the back-end using Postman or some equivalent with a resource that doesn't exist, is there a response that comes back? It may be that the server isn't returning a response. Or at least, it's not returning a response that the `HttpClient` can decipher.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in the event of an error, your

```
data => {
       this.transactionResponse = data;
```

code does not get called - you got an **error** response, not a normal response afterall.

Try to get the information from the

```
 }, (err) => { this.transactionResponse = err
```

part.

Comment: The error message indicates, that your error response does not contains a "_errorMessages" property. What does this show you in the console upon error?  `(err) => { console.log("error object:", err); }`
You should bind your transactionResponse local object accordingly.

Comment: ForestG, my error response does contain a _message property though. Here's the console.log I get: "error object: Http failure response for http://~/api/transactions/U004/search/bill/B123: 404 Not Found"

Comment: This is the message your browser lets through to your app. You can work from there: just simply set your this.transactionResponse by hand in the error handling.

Comment: I tried to do that but it is undefined. How do I define it in the error when I only define it in the subscribe?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a [typed response:](https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-4-3-httpclient-accessing-rest-web-services-with-angular/)

On your `error` notification type you could have something like:

```
err =>  {
        this.localErrorResponse = err as ErrorResponse;
        this._order= this.localErrorResponse._order;
      }
```

inside your class, also, you could have:

```
import { ErrorResponse } from './error-response';

localErrorResponse: ErrorResponse;
_order: string;
```

and then, you could have your `ErrorResponse` class like:

```
import { ErrorDetail } from './error-detail';

export class ErrorResponse{
  _transactionNumber: number;
  _order: string;
  _errorDetails: ErrorDetail;
}
```

and class `ErrorDetail`

```
export class ErrorDetail {
  _status: number;
  _message: string
}
```

then you can map some other variables, as `_order` (`this._order`), or get them from your `localErrorResponse` (`this.localErrorResponse`) variable

Answer (score 0):

> I have a service call that when it returns a 404 error, I want to
>   display the message that comes from the server when the status is 404

...

> I bind to the transactionResponse object that I get back from my
>   service call. Unfortunately, although I believe this should work, I
>   get the issue that _errorDetails is undefined and so nothing shows up.

Try this:

[StackBlitz EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-error-msg)

Comment: I'm trying to get back the data from my json object not the default server error.

Comment: @Euridice01, when return this data `{  
       "_transactionNumber":null,
       "_order":null,
       "_errorDetails":{  
          "_status":"404",
          "_message":"Number is not available"
       }
    }` did you return `status code` in header?